# Can I replace Salesforce home page with a Visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce

Is there a way to have all of my Salesforce users land on a Visualforce page when they they log in instead of the standard Salesforce home page?

I know I can add links in the left margin, but I want to control their initial view of Salesforce even more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a custom tab linked to a Visualforce page, then configure that tab to be the landing page of your app. You do that under Apps

Setup > Create > Apps > (your app) > edit

[image]